# set first check box checked and others disable from checkbox list in clientside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Checkbox list. On the load of a page i want my first checkbox true and others are disable.I need to check only one checkbox from checkbox list and others should be disable.If use unchecked the checked checkbox then others should be enable means allowed only one check box checked.

My javascript code is here but on the load of page its not checked the first checkbox, also i want the id of each checkbox while using checkboxlist.

```
function CheckOptions(CheckBoxList) {
         var checkboxlist = document.getElementById('CheckBoxList1');

            var checkedCount = 0;
            var options = CheckBoxList.getElementsByTagName('input');                
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                if (options[i].checked) {                       
                    checkedCount += 1;
                }
            }

            if (checkedCount > 0) {
                for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
                    if (!options[j].checked)
                        options[j].disabled = true;

                }                }
           else {
                for (var k = 0; k < options.length; k++) {
                    options[k].disabled = false;
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: For solving this this you can use radio buttons..

Comment: You should consider using Radio buttons. The behavior you're after is their default behavior. Besides, it seems looking at your code that your checkboxes share the same ID. This won't work as the ID must be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Sorry but I can't use RadiobuttonList. I must have use only CheckBoxList not even CheckBoxes. Please help.

Comment: You should use Set<Class> elements in which maintain Radio button id.

Answer (score 4):

If you're only wanting one checked at a time, it sounds like a group of radio buttons would better serve your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    var checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]");

    // select the first one on load
    checkboxes.eq(0).attr("checked", "checked");
    checkboxes.each(function(i, e) {
        if (i > 0) {
            $(e).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    })

    // handle further selections:
    checkboxes.click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            var t = this;
            checkboxes.each(function(i, e) {
                if (e != t) {
                    $(e).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        } else {
            checkboxes.attr("disabled", null)
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: no i can't use Radiobutton list. I have to use only check box list not even checkboxes. One more thing, I have a four items in my check box list i.e Today,Month,Week,Date.When i checked on Date then i have a panel which should be visible on the check of 'Date'. Please help.

Comment: Hello piotrb, Your's given code is not working and what to write at onclick event of CheckboxList. Please help it's urgent.

Comment: Hi. Can you post your html code? If it's generated by asp/php/anything else, please post the generated code.